# Open source internal (enterprise) survey software with LDAP integration?

Tags: linux, survey, intranet, ldap

I'm looking for a simple webservice that allows organization members to record their yes/no answer to a question in a database and have the answers be publicly or privately viewable. It would be hosted internally behind the firewall.

It needs to support LDAP authentication for the survey takers.

I'm tempted to roll my own, but it seems unlikely that something like this does not already exist.

I did look into LimeSurvey, but it does not seem to support LDAP authentication of survey takers out of the box. Someone describes [a hack](https://www.limesurvey.org/forum/can-i-do-this-with-limesurvey/100702-ldap-authentication-for-survey-access) (which I don't fully understand) to accomplish this, but it's clearly outside of the software's intended purpose. Rather, their LDAP authentication seems to be targeted toward survey creators.

Ideally, this software would support both authenticated survey creation and survey taking.

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic for superuser. I'll be migrating this to SR, though some *slight* extra polish would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to limesurvey, if you can not get ldap to work, is to use a content management/framework like drupal with its modules that address your requirements. I do something similar on an intranet using:

1. [Ldap](https://www.drupal.org/project/ldap) module for ldap integration
2. [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module to create the surveys
3. Access to the surveys/results will be based on assigned roles etc